# Accessing view's custom property in Xamarin.UiTest

Tags: xamarin.android, android-custom-view, xamarin.uitest

I have a custom android view class created with Android Class Library project called "components" with custom properties defined in Resources/values/Attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="SwitchWithData">
   ...
    <attr name="isOn" format="boolean"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Custom view class is defined in CustomView.cs with public property .

```
 public bool IsOn {
        get { return _isOn; }
        set { _isOn = value; SeIsOn(value); }
    }
```

When working with custom view in layout or from code, i can access the property.

android project with reference to components project -
resource/layout.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">
                    ...
                    <Components.CustomView  
                     app:IsOn="true"
                     android:id="@+id/CustomView"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Even accessing property from code is working fine. - MainActivity.cs

```
    customView = FindViewById<Components.CustomView>(Resource.Id.CustomView);
    customView.IsOn = true;
```

So the problem is to access this property from Xamarin.UiTest project. Usually i accessed properties by calling invoke method like this.

```
app.Query(x => x.Id("Switch").Invoke("isChecked").Value<bool>()).First();
```

this is working fine with android native view's, but when im trying use the same method to access my custom view's propery it is returning empty object.

```
app.Query(x => x.Id("CustomView").Invoke("isOn").Value<bool>()).First();
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Jan, I'm not sure you have enough reputation yet, but if possible, please add your solution as a answer to your own question and mark it as the correct answer. This way, you will reach more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ive figgured it out. The problem was in component class.According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors) There has to be a method with an named Export attribute.

```
    [Export("IsSwitchedOn")]
    public bool IsSwitchedOn() {
        return IsOn;
    }
```

Than you can access the method in UiTest like this.

```
app.Query(x => x.Id("CustomView").Invoke("IsSwitchedOn"));
```